# reactjs - jest snapshot testing nested redux "connected" components

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

When snapshot testing (jest snapshot) a component which is connected to redux store I can export the actual component in addition to the connected component

```
// User.js

/* ... */

export class User extends React.Component {/* ... */}

/* ... */

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(User);
```

In the test file I can import the actual component (not the connected version) and do snapshot testing on it.

```
// User.spec.js

import { User } from './User';

/* ... toMatchSnapshot() testing */
```

But I run into issues when a connected component is nested inside another connected component. For example, let's say `User` component is nested inside another connected component -

```
// Wrapper.js

import User from './User'; // importing the connected version

/* ... */

export class Wrapper extends React.Component {

  /* ... */

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        /* ... */
        <User />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Wrapper);
```

When running snapshot test on `Wrapper` the same way I did on `User` gives me the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(User)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(User)".`
```

Is there any way to shallow render when snapshotting? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case the best way is to test the `Wrapper` on its own by just mocking `User`

```
import Wrapper from './Wrapper'

jest.mock('./User', () => 'User') // note that the path to user is relative the test file not to  the Wrapper.js file.
```

This will replace `User` with a simple component with name `User`.

Comment: Hi I am still facing same error after making changes

Comment: Error console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
   Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small tweak to the answer provided by @andreas-köberle as it may produce the error: `using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements`

To fix that if you want to mock a component it should return a fn. Example reflects multi word naming:

`jest.mock('./User', () => () => 'UserThingStuff')`

or to return an HTML element:

`jest.mock('./User', () => 'user-thing-stuff')`

Answer (score 0):

You can add Mock store & then test component withougth connect, but with nested connect Components ↓

Component withought connect,
but include nested connected Elements ->

test with mocking store, which state can configure.↓
before test : npm install redux-mock-store --save-dev

test.js ↓

```
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

//create mockStore
let mockStore;
//create Obj for config store
const mockStoreConf = configureStore([]);
//configure store (add states)
mockStore = mockStoreConf({
    someStateInMockStore: `SomeValueFromMockKetInMockStore`,
       });
const tree = renderer.create(
      <Provider store={mockStore}>
        <Component />
      </Provider>
    );
expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Now your Component's nested connected children take state from your mockStore.
Just add needed states on configuration step (//configure store (add states)).

information from https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-connected-component-test